# Actual definition of a Message Digest?

Tags: hash

I'm having a hard time to find a clear and definitive definition of what a Message Digest is in regards to hashing algorithms.

Some sources state it's the hashing function itself. Other sources state it's the *output* from the hashing function after some input is passed through it (ie: the actual hash). Other sources state it's a technique that involves both.

What is a clear definition of a Message Digest?

Comment: It is always useful to link to the sources you reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The Message Digest is the output of a hash function.**

The confusion likely stems from the "message-digest algorithms", to which MD5 belongs. After all, MD5 just means "message-digest algorithm 5". This may be the reason why some sources claim that "message digest is an algorithm", rather than the output of one.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Does this mean the Message Digest is synonymous with the hash value?

Comment: @user4779 Yes. Usually, people say "hash" as noun when they refer to the output ("The hash of this file is ...") or "hash" as verb when they mean the process of calculating the message digest ("Then the data is hashed"),

Comment: @user4779 The hash value is often binary, while the message digest is the hash value converted to a character string (typically hex or base 64). So they're isomorphic.